# I cannot run my android emulator on visual studio what could be the problem on this?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM1VH.png)[enter image description here][2]

Device error: emulator: Android emulator version 30.1.5.0 (build_id 6855416) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'pixel_2_q_10_0_-_api_29'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\

emulator: emuDirName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\

emulator: Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.

Comment: [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/emulator-does-not-work/1071008) I found a similar thread. It seems that the issue has been fixed in the latest VS release.

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask